# react-testing-library: Render prop - Expected mock function to have been last called with: [false] But it was not called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Today I am facing an issue with tests using `react-testing-library`.

For some reason, `react-testing-library` doesn't seem to understand that the render prop has been called. More precisely, it doesn't seem to re-render children after first render.

The code looks like this (simplified)

**index.test.js**

```
    // Simplified code, this is one test

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const renderCallback = jest.fn();
    const mockResolvers = { 
      // Some mock GraphQL resolvers
    }

    render(
      <ReduxMockingProvider initialState={initialState}>
        <ApolloMockingProvider mockResolvers={mockResolvers}>
          <SomeComponent waitUntilResolved>
            {renderCallback}
          </SomeComponent>
        </ApolloMockingProvider>
      </ReduxMockingProvider>,
    );

    await jest.runAllTicks();
    expect(renderCallback).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(false);
```

**index.js**

```
  <SomeComponent waitUntilResolved>
    {(result) => {
      const data = result.data;

      return (
        <SomeQueryComponent
          query={someQueryHere}
          variables={{
        // Some variables from data
          }}
        >
          {({ loading, error, data: someData }) => {
            if (loading) {
              return (props.waitUntilResolved) ? null : props.children({ loading });
            }

            if (error) return props.children(false);

            return props.children(someData);
          }}
        </SomeQueryComponent>
      );
    }}
  </SomeComponent>
```

Unfortunately when I run the test like this it doesn't pass :

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been last called with:
      [false]
    But it was not called.
```

If I add `props.children(false)` before `if (loading) {} condition` it works fine.

If I `console.log` from within the index.js, I can see that the code reaches the very end i.e before `return props.children(someData)` but `react-testing-library` doesn't understand that there is a rerender and that the render prop is called once again.

Has anyone come across such an issue yet ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

And of course right after asking, I finally stumble across the bug/solution.

The issue was that timers weren't ran.

Adding `await jest.runAllTimers();` and resetting their modules with

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
```

fixed it !